# What is the maximum size of a set A such that any subset of size k is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set A of vectors in $\mathbb{F}^n_p$, where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite field. My question is:

What is the maximum size of the set A such that any subset of size $k$ is linearly independent?

For example, for $n=6,p=2$ and $k=6$, we know that the answer is 6. Because we can not have more than six linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{F}^2_6$. But if we consider $k=5$ or less it is clear that the size of A must be greater than equal to $6$. But I am interested in the largest possible size of such a set for fixed values of $n,p,$ and $k$.

Is there any construction method for such a set?